# Cannot disable resume partition/file on Debian Linux 10 buster

Tags: linux, debian, initramfs

When I `sudo update-initramfs -u` I get this information message:

I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda4
I: (UUID=6511e9fe-a340-4e5f-b42d-19acd4211b35)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.

I want to completely disable resume feature, I don't use hibernation.

I tried changing this file, but it makes no difference.
`/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

Tried these options:

RESUME=
RESUME=None
RESUME=none

No effect. I also deleted it completely (`/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`) no change either.

As a workaround, I used kernel parametre `noresume` but I'm curious how to change the setting for `update-initramfs` to stop using a partition for resume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RESUME=none` definitely works for me to disable resume in Debian Buster 10.3. It is case-sensitive.

```
# cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
RESUME=none
```

Comment: Is your system cleanly Debian buster 10 formated or updated from previous versions? I noticed that on my formated from scratch as Debian buster systems (2 laptops) the setting you mentioned does not make any difference. But on an older system initially formatted with Debian Wheezy 7 and upgraded to 8, 9, 10, the setting indeed makes changes. Whenever I mention 10, I mean 10.3, all systems fully updated.

Comment: It's a 10.3 system upgraded from debian 9

Answer (score 0):

After modifying

```
/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

contents to

```
RESUME=none
```

apply the setting by executing

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Just changing the file won't change your system settings.

Comment: The question says that the OP is already doing this.