# Kubuntu takes more than 2 minutes to boot!

Tags: partition, dual-boot, gparted, kubuntu

Okay... so I did something which I was probably not supposed to do. I have a 256 GB SSD. GParted from a live Kubuntu CD showed that I have 16gb of unallocated space. I wanted to add it to the root partition. However, there were swap and boot partitions between the unallocated space and the root partition, so I first added the space to boot partition, then shrunk the boot partition from left, then repeated the same with swap, and finally added it to root partition. To be safe, I reinstalled grub. Now, my Windows continues taking around 10s to boot, while Kubuntu takes more than a couple of minutes. Why is this so? If I did break something, why does it boot at all?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you recreate the swap partition?  I've had a similar issue when I've messed with the swap partition.

Comment: @Oskar Skog Yes I did. But how to know that my system uses it, or does it do by default on detecting a swap partition?

Comment: Ok swap wasn't activated. Activated it. Will try rebooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!!
My swap space was in /dev/nvme0n1p6, so I ran:
`sudo swapoff -a`
`sudo mkswap -L swap /dev/nvme0n1p6` and
`sudo swapon -a`.
Then I disabled some startup services, and finally commented out the swap line from /etc/fstab. Don't know whether `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10` helped or not, but after rebooting, `systemd-analyze` showed 14.385s, as compared to around 2min 25s before.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I think I figured out your problem; the system looks for the resume partition, which is the swap actually and was changed.

When you boot do you see a graphic screen? Press something to view messages. The delay is usually presented (waiting... something like that)

Try this:
[disable resume partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583514/cannot-disable-resume-partition-file-on-debian-linux-10-buster)

Unless you need hibernation; in that case you need to find the new uuid of swap partition and correct `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file.

Also check the `/etc/fstab` file. You should correct this one too, in order to have swap available to the system.

Comment: My /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/ is empty

Comment: ok. Check /etc/fstab. There must be a line mentioning 'swap'. Is it using UUID or label or device to mount?

Comment: # swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=3e406cde-3fb9-4a61-8f9b-94dbabf496a6 none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: ```blkid``` says UUID is this: c990c576-f89b-4b9b-8101-7eda135e2503 and PARTUUID: 0fe287ae-6eab-4320-9d92-5fe5cd291678

Comment: Why the UUID's shown in fstab and by blkid different?

Comment: Because you've just located the problem! Use the UUID of `blkid`, correct the one in fstab.

Comment: It seems that when you did the tasks you mentioned in the question, the swap partition changed UUID. So now, the system tries to find it when booting and fails. They delay is probably when trying to locate the old uuid swap and use it.

Comment: oops. The /etc/fstab line mentioning swap should not have # at start of line. That's a comment. Any line mentioning swap sw without # ?

Comment: Yes, the one I added in a comment above

Comment: UUID=c990c576-f89b-4b9b-8101-7eda135e2503 none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: Sorry to not mention that, but after 'installation', there was a new line

Comment: Ok, you corrected it. Is it ok now?

Comment: I just rebooted, pressed ```Esc``` on splash, it showed what was going on. It took 1min 30s on something like 'A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/'the new uuid''

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109331/discussion-between-akshat-vats-and-krackout).

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but I don't have enough points.

Try `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame`. The 1st one shows the time it took to boot, the 2nd shows how much time each service takes to start. It'll help you find where the delay occurs.

Comment: The firmware took 2.731s, loader 4.365, kernel 33.455s, userspace 1min 39.228s. That means kernel and userspace are taking abnormal time. Solution?

Comment: `systemd-analyze blame` results?

Comment: It is rather long, how do I tell you?

Comment: free -m says 0 swap size

Comment: Check the time for each service, they are sorted. Locate the one or ones that delay.

Comment: https://ibb.co/T2nzmwZ

Comment: https://ibb.co/2sdnKCR

Comment: 30ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                                                             
  29ms rsyslog.service